# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode '\xc3\xa8' together with '\xe8'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I am having this strange problem below:

```
>>> a=u'Pal-Andr\xe8'
>>> b='Pal-Andr\xc3\xa8'
>>> print "%s %s" % (a,b) # boom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print "%s" % a
Pal-Andrè
>>> print "%s" % b
Pal-Andrè
```

Where I can print **a**, **b** separately but not both.

What's the problem? How can I print them both?

Comment: the char doesn't have representation in ASCII format it should be unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is

```
b = 'Pal-Andr\xc3\xa8'
```

Now, `b` has a string literal not a unicode literal. So, when you are printing them as strings separately, `a` is treated as a Unicode String and `b` is treated as a normal string.

```
>>> "%s" % a
u'Pal-Andr\xe8'
>>> "%s" % b
'Pal-Andr\xc3\xa8'
```

Note the `u` at the beginning is missing. You can confirm further

```
>>> type("%s" % b)
<type 'str'>
>>> type("%s" % a)
<type 'unicode'>
```

But when you are printing them together, string becomes a unicode string and `\xc3` is not a valid ASCII code and that is why the code is failing.

To fix it, you simply have to declare `b` also as a unicode literal, like this

```
>>> a=u'Pal-Andr\xe8'
>>> b=u'Pal-Andr\xc3\xa8'
>>> "%s" % a
u'Pal-Andr\xe8'
>>> "%s" % b
u'Pal-Andr\xc3\xa8'
>>> "%s %s" % (a, b)
u'Pal-Andr\xe8 Pal-Andr\xc3\xa8'
```

Comment: My problem is : **b** is given by an input that I could not have control of. How would I convert **b** to unicode?

Comment: @chfw You might have to decode with the proper encoding, like this `b.decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the real issue here, but one thing for sure **a** is a unicode string and **b** is a string.

You will have to encode or decode one of them before print them both.

Here is an example.

```
>>> b = b.decode('utf-8') 
>>> print u"%s %s" % (a,b)
Pal-Andrè Pal-Andrè
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a mix of Unicode and byte strings makes the combined print try to promote everything to Unicode strings.  You've got to decode the byte string with the correct codec, else Python 2 will default to `ascii`.  `b` is a byte string encoded in UTF-8.  The format string is promoted as well, but it happens to work decoded from ASCII.  Best to use Unicode everywhere:

```
>>> print u'%s %s' % (a,b.decode('utf8'))
Pal-Andrè Pal-Andrè
```